# How would you alter this template to properly render this HTML code after this boolean is set?

Tags: react-native

The question title might be vague but let's clear that up now.

So, I have a bit of conditional rendering going on and I need to display what I'm calling a "Manage Account" template after Registering a new user. Basically, I need to display some HTML code after register. So upon Registration, a user should be directed to the "Manage Account" template/view.

My code makes sense, to me at least, but it's just not working. I'd really appreciate it if someone could chime in an suggest any changes I should make to get this thing to work properly.

Here's my code!:

```
return (
    (!afterLogin &&
    (afterRegister ||
    (!showRegisterForm && (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress = {onPressLogin}
          style={styles.loginBtn}>
          <Text>Log in.</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {setShowRegisterForm(!showRegisterForm)}}
            style={styles.registerBtn}
            title='Register'
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )))) || 
    (!afterRegister &&
    (showRegisterForm &&
      <View>
        <Text>Registration Form.</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder='First name' onChangeText={text => setFirstName(text)} style={styles.registerFormField}></TextInput>
        <TextInput placeholder='Last name' onChangeText={text => setLastName(text)} style={styles.registerFormField}></TextInput>
        <TextInput placeholder='Email address' onChangeText={text => setUserEmail(text)} style={styles.registerFormField}></TextInput>
        <TextInput placeholder='Password' onChangeText={text => setUserPassword(text)} style={styles.registerFormField} secureTextEntry></TextInput>
        <TextInput placeholder='Confirm password' onChangeText={text => setConfirmPassword(text)} style={styles.registerFormField} secureTextEntry></TextInput>
        <Button onPress={submitRegistrationForm} title='Register'/>
      </View>
    )) ||
    (afterLogin && 
      <View>
          <Text>Manage Account.</Text>
          <Button onPress={stripeOnboarding} title='Connect with Stripe'/>
      </View>
    ) ||
    (afterRegister &&
      <View>
        <Text>Manage Account.</Text>
        <Button onPress={stripeOnboarding} title='Connect with Stripe'/>
      </View>
    ) // this was my best stab at solving this problem
  );
```

The `afterRegister` boolean is being set in the callback function `submitRegistrationForm`. It just changes it to true rather than false.

Is there a combination I'm missing here? Mind you, that after logging in successfully, the user is directed to the "Manage Account" page successfully. I figured since that is working, that I could just copy the same sort of pattern used for that bit of functionality to the Register -> Manage Account interaction/feature.

You guys are the geniuses, you tell me. What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code easier to read I replaced the render blocks with meaningful functions and organized the conditions of the same layer on top of each other:

```
  return (
    (!afterLogin && (afterRegister || (!showRegisterForm && (renderLoginForm())))) ||
    (!afterRegister && (showRegisterForm && renderRegisterForm())) ||
    (afterLogin && renderManageAccount()) ||
    (afterRegister && renderManageAccount())
  );
```

Now looking at the code the second thing we need to get rid of, is the long chain of conditions which is confusing. Separate each conditional rendering with its own combination of conditions. So in your case there would be three separate combinations; one for the log in form, another for the register form and the third for the manage account component.

```
  return (<>
    {!afterLogin && !afterRegister && !showRegisterForm && renderLoginForm()}
    {!afterLogin && !afterRegister && showRegisterForm && renderRegisterForm()}
    {(afterLogin || afterRegister) && renderManageAccount()}
  </>);
```

After this code refactor, it should be much easier for you to modify the code logic as you wish. I didn't fully understand your booleans so the above code is a rough example of how to go about this. Hope it helped.

Comment: I appreciate this! Thank you very much.

Comment: So, those functions you made, do I just make a function sort of like this to return the template code?: `const renderLoginForm = () => { return (<View><Text>Blah etc.</Text></View>);} `

Comment: Yes @xccelerated99 I would recommend creating such functions that return a react component. Basically creating react components.

Comment: Awesome. Just tried implementing your suggestions and the templates are rendering fine.

Comment: Uh... hey S J. I just realized that I actually want to go from the Registration form to the Login form. Not from Registration to Manage Account. Could you post an update?

Comment: You think this would work?: `((!afterLogin && !showRegisterForm) || (afterRegister) && (renderLoginForm()))` I want to render the Login form afterRegistration.

Comment: You can do it yourself, just know when combining conditions the symbol || is like OR gate it will return true if either side were true. So when you say (condition1 || condition2) && renderSomething() this will render if either condition1 or condition2 is true. The symbol && will go condition by condition and all must be true to eventually call any expression ahead. If one condition in the line was false it breaks this line and moves to the next.

Comment: Yes your condition looks correct

Comment: Sort of love you S J. Thanks for your help. Sometimes my brain doesn't compute but your logic is very straightforward. You made this very simple and easy to understand. Please buy yourself a beer or 3 later. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome, honestly we all tend to go there. Thats why always follow a minimalistic approach. My mentor used to say, when debugging your code explain it to a rubber duck. It's meant to make you go over your code and break it down line by line to follow through your logic. Cheers!